# Put Lollipop into Silent Mode/Mute Mode not Priority Mode

Tags: android

At the moment I am using the following to put the phone into Silent Mode:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

But I have noticed that in Lollipop it puts the phone into "Priority Mode" with a little star at the top in the notification bar. But I want it to be 100% silent and not "Priority Mode". Is this possible? To set Lollipop to be 100% silent?

I have tried to set the setRingerMode to 0 like this

```
audioManager.setRingerMode(0);
```

But it still gives me the star instead of the the speaker with the line through it and it says Vibrate with (Priority) in brackets under it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Android 5.0.X, calling `setRingerMode(RINGER_MODE_SILENT)` would (i) trigger the "priority mode", which would (ii) subsequently trigger a change of the ringer mode back to RINGER_MODE_NORMAL.

A brutal workaround, exploiting a bug in Android 5.0.X, is to issue the `setRingerMode(RINGER_MODE_SILENT)` call again in a short time (say 500ms) after action (ii) above is triggered.  But this is of course not proper and should cease to work in Android 5.1.X.

The proper way to achieve 100% silence in 5.X would be to switch to the "None" interruption mode.  This could be achieved by creating a service extending `NotificationListenerService`, registering it, and providing a function to set the interruption mode by calling `requestInterruptionFilter(INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE)` in the service. [Here (Noyze app)](https://github.com/Tombarr/Noyze/blob/master/src/main/java/me/barrasso/android/volume/MediaControllerService.java) is an example.  You can then invoke the function from your activity to switch to the mode.

For this to work you would need the `BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` permission, and an explicit grant of notification access by the user.

Caution: as you may be aware `INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE` really means 100% silence, and Alarm clock would cease to work.

Comment: This is the way to go. Unfortunately, Google says changing to RINGER_SILENT_MODE will switch to Priority, I checked that is not true for all devices. requestInterruptionFilter seems the way to go (and the only way for activate None mode). But it is a pain that the user has to explicitly gives permission...

Answer (score 0):

Google has removed silent mode from lollipop. Here [is the link to official android issue page](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78652).

> Setting the device to RINGER_MODE_SILENT causes the device to enter
>   the new priority mode. The device leaves priority mode if you set it
>   to RINGER_MODE_NORMAL or RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE.

You read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#BehaviorNotifications).

Comment: That is disappointing that they did that. I want my phone to go into silent mode 100% at work and now I have to do this manually every day?

Comment: unfortunately yes but you can use vibrate mode or use priority mode and set priority. you will have to search for tutorials though.

Comment: I just wrote an app that works on pre Lollipop, but not on lollipop, this is very disappointing.

Comment: same here. I have nexus 4 and i am completely disappointed with google.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by calling `setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)` twice because Lollipop first places the device into Priority mode than into Silent mode.

```
final AudioManager audiomanage = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audiomanage.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                audiomanage.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);             
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: This is a bug in Android 5.0, which has been fixed in Android 5.1.  The code only works on 5.0.