# Android 5.1 set to priority mode

Tags: android, audio, silent, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm currently trying to set a phone running android 5.1 to the priority mode.

I tried to set it to silent mode in the AudioManager but this shows no effect as well as setting it to zero.

Setting it to Vibration-Mode works though...

```
//Neither this
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT); 

//nor this works
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setRingerMode(0);
```

I haven't found any other solution by now.

Also I can't use any root features.

EDIT: Just found out that setting it to 0 (or RINGER_MODE_SILENT) does not do nothing: It takes me out of Vibration mode if I'm in...

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that I can achieve it through the NotificationListener Service.
(And that my question already has an answer somewhere else...)

```
    //In the Service I use this to enable and disable silent mode(or priority...)
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        boolean start = intent.getBooleanExtra("start", false);
        if(start)
        {
            Log.d("TAG","START");

            //Check if at least Lollipop, otherwise use old method
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                requestInterruptionFilter(INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
            else{
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("TAG","STOP");
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                requestInterruptionFilter(INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);
            else{
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }
```

Comment: Yes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153984/put-lollipop-into-silent-mode-mute-mode-not-priority-mode